# Exercise LP Relaxation

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, relaxations

> $\max Z = 6x_1 + 7x_2$
>
> Constraints:
>
> $-2x_1 + 2x_2 \le 3\\
> 7x_1 + 3x_2 \le 22$
>
> $x_1,x_2 \ge 0$ and $x_1, x_2 \in \Bbb Z$

How to solve this problem with relaxation LP by graphical method?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: I have found that the optimal soluiton by Graphical Method is x1 = 1.75 and x2 = 3.25.

Comment: But I didnt understand what I need to do in this problem to find the relaxation solution

Comment: Is there some example of an non linear relaxation??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dtzutovcd8

$x_1 =3$, $x_2 =4$ doesn't satisfy one of your equations ($7x+3y \le 22)$.

The only integer values that satisfy the constraints are: $(x_1,x_2)=\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2), (2,0),(2,1),(2,2),(3,0)\}$

Comment: Integer solution should be $(2,2)$. So, $Z=26$

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: But What I need to do to find the relaxation solution by graphical method??